# How to change method order intellij?

Tags: methods, intellij-idea, intellij-14

Assume I have a class written as below

```
public MyClass{

   public void method2(){

   }

   public void method1(){

   }

}
```

but I would like to see method1() appearing first and method2() appearing second.

Is there anyway to do that with intellij without manually copy pasting? I cant find any tool inside **method summary window**.

Comment: Ctrl + shift + (UP/DOWN arrow) (by default) moves your block (where cursor is) up and down.

Comment: `Alt + Shift + Up/Down arrow` can also move your codes anywhere. Or you can see the keymap here: https://resources.jetbrains.com/assets/products/intellij-idea/IntelliJIDEA_ReferenceCard.pdf

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you only want to move the method **up/down** you can simply select it and use`ctrl + shift + (up/down)` in order to move it as wished.